# How can an outdoor portable air conditioner detect the right temperature inside?

Tags: hvac, portable-ac

I am growing plants indoor and I need some cooling which I can only achieve with an air-conditioner. Let's also say that I can only use a portable unit. The issue is that I don't want to use single hose portable air conditioner units and don't want want to put the AC unit inside my grow room because 1. the inside humidity is very high and I don't want that to mess up my air-conditioner and vice versa 2. I don't want negative pressure that is so common with portable airconditioners. So I rather want to went the cool air flow into my growing room and keep the portable AC unit outside.

So, I found the below [unit](https://www.pearl.de/a-REF75023-3033.shtml?vid=917&wa_id=40&wa_num=5120&utm_source=googleps&utm_medium=cpc&gclid=EAIaIQobChMI7cvu4enB8gIVVeN3Ch19dwBlEAQYASABEgJ9kPD_BwE) but my question is that when this portable AC unit is outside, how is it even going to detect and maintain the inside temperature? Is it just pure marketing or could there be an actual basis to this claim that it can work from outside as well? Because my current understanding is that the AC units detect temperature when the air from the cool room is put outside through the exhaust.

[image]

Comment: Does it have a temperature sensor?

Comment: The AC unit does (like the portable air conditioners) i.e. it does allow to set the required temperature.

Comment: Does this unit have a hand held remote control? If so, it detects the temp inside and regulates the outside unit by wireless communication.

Comment: Can you find a manual and post the relevant sections here?  That would help.  Also, the same manufacturer makes evaporative air coolers.  Maybe one of those would suit your needs more?

Comment: Why not contact the seller or manufacturer and ask?

Comment: @Mark I contacted but no response. I will post my answer (or mark the right one) once I have the unit.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest exploring the outdoor heat pump that connects an indoor unit with a built-in thermostat like [this](https://www.mitsubishicomfort.com/residential?campaign_id=70131000001yHC6AAM&msclkid=2da99652ef7811829bf2f77211ea8ffa&utm_source=Bing&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=MSN_B_CBU_Mitsubishi%20Electric_MB&utm_term=%2Bmitsubishi%20%2Bac&utm_content=Cooling).

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

It likely has some sort of temp sensor on the intake (assuming it has one even) If it doesn't then it really cant unless there's some sort of thermostat that is connected to it through the window.

If you own the place you are staying then I +1 the mini split system, they are WAY more efficient than any window or portable AC system on the market. They all around just work better if you can add it. If its a rental you will need permission from the property owner/manager (get it in writing) if they will even allow you to add it at all.  If they wont then you are stuck with a through the window unit.